# Session variable does not maintain value across different controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session

I am working with two controllers, they both save a value to `Session` but only one of the `Controller` manages to maintain it's value.

The line of code that saves the value is

```
Session["LoginDate"] = <dateTimeObject>;
```

and this is the same in both `Controllers`. The Second controller gets called from the First Controller and while in the second controller, if I set the value of `Session` then we're ok until I get back in the calling controller. If I call the First controller only, the value can get set and be sent back to the client.

I have tried modifying the second config file to include

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="30" />
```

and have made sure they are at the same version of .NET, MVC, etc...

Any ideas as to how to debug this? What else should I check?

**UPDATE** 
Is there a way to pass the session state from different servers or would usign cookies be better since the cookie will be on the client browser? The new discovery is that the second controller does an

`Redirect("serverOfController_1");`

Answer (score 1):

The controller gets initialised by the MVC core, so that it has the correct references to the context of the current request. When you create an instance of a controller yourself, that won't have any context at all, so it can't use anything from the controller interface.

For a method in that controller to work in that context, it can't rely on anything in the controller interface. If you want to set a session variable from that method, you have to get the current context and access the `Session` object from that:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["LoginDate"] = <dateTimeObject>;
```

You can also copy the controller context from the current controller after you have created the instance. That way the controller that you created will have the same context as the current controller. Example:

```
SecondController second = new SecondController();
second.ControllerContext = ControllerContect;
second.SomeMethod();
```